# jquery ellipsis doesn't show dots at the end

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, ellipsis

[Jquery Ellipsis](https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/jquery-ellipsis) doesn't show three dots at the end.

HTML:

```
<div class="slidertext three_lines">SIA “Baltic Metolat” provides mechanical surface treatment, priming and painting of technical task. We are able to handle oversized items.</div>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery('.three_lines').ellipsis({
    row: 3
});
```

CSS:

```
.slidertext {
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 58px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 224px;
}
```

It shows only three lines, but it doesn't show dots at the end.

Live it could be seen here: http://www.metolat.lv/ (search fo text "provides mechanical surface").

Comment: That live example doesn't look like the text is getting shortened at all.  It shows 3 lines because the fourth line is hidden due to a fixed height and hidden overflow of its container.

Comment: Really! So then the question is why it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That live example doesn't look like the text is getting shortened at all. It shows 3 lines because the fourth line is hidden due to a fixed height and hidden overflow of its container.

It looks like that Ellipsis plugin calculates whether a text element needs to be truncated by comparing its total height to the height of n (here, 3) lines.  Since you have a fixed height set in CSS for that div, the plugin looks at it and says to itself "that element has a height less than or equal to the height of 3 lines of text" and so it doesn't do anything.

You are calling it correctly, though, and I see that it works on your title "Metal construction..."

Comment: Yep. Disabling the `height` rule, and executing `.ellipsis()` again shows the expected truncation.

Comment: Btw, what if I need min-height for element? How to fix this? If there are just two lines then it would be a problem?